# Error when creating global variable in Javascript Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to create a page variable that can be used by my Scroller class for infinite scrolling.  I need it to be global I think, so that it remembers itself outside the ajax function.

```
class Scroller {
  window.page = 1;

  constructor(){
    this.events();
  }

  events(){
    $(document).on("scroll", this.on_scroll.bind(this))
  }

  on_scroll(e){
    var scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop();
    var body_height = $('body').height();
    var win_height = $(window).height();
    var height_diff = body_height - win_height;


    if( (scroll_top+1 >= height_diff) && working==false){
        working=true;
        console.log("greater than diff");
        this.load_more();
    }
    else{
        //console.log(scroll_top);
        //console.log("greater than diff");
    }

}
```

I also tried:

```
var page = 1;
page = 1;
$page = 1;
```

all of these give an error, usually a syntax error.  What is the best way to make a global variable in a class? or any variable for passing to the scroll function that is being called.  I also need those so I can create a 'working' variable so that ajax doesn't load multiple times.

Thanks for any help

Comment: see if declaring it outside the class does the work

Comment: Declare it outside of the class and assign to it inside the class. Both inside and outside will reference the same variable. That's what being global typically means. In web, global typically means the `window` object, but there are exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just define it in the constructor if it's not already defined:

```
class Scroller {
    constructor() {
        window.page = window.page || 1;
        this.events();
    }
}
```

That being said, there's a serious design smell here. You might as well just define the variable outside the class.

Note also that it doesn't have to be global; you can define it on the class object itself and refer to it as `Scroller.page`:

```
class Scroller {
    /* ... */
}

Scroller.page = 1;
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"a serious design smell"*?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Polluting the global namespace with unqualified random variables? What if the next script you load also decides to use a global `page` variable to do something entirely different?

Comment: *"A design smell"* has multiple meanings, some good, some bad. That's why I asked.

Comment: This is too much for beginners, for a simple variable. That makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can either define it inside the `constructor` (I would suggest that)

```
class Scroller {
  constructor(){
    this.page = 1;
    this.events();
  }
}
```

and later change it with `this.page = 2` (or whatever)

Or if you really really need it a global outside the Class like this

```
window.page = 1;
class Scroller {
    constructor(){  
        this.events();
      }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This also works, as you are asking. It might be not recommended!

Global variables can cause headaches and memory leaks.

It is also a pain when working at many on the same code.

```js
function notinglobalScope(){
  window["page"] = 1
}
notinglobalScope()


console.log(page)
```

Better way is to store your data in a separate object.

This way you can add as many variables you need, accessible from anywhere.

It stay cleaner and simple to use.

```js
var config = {}

function notinglobalScope(){
  config.page = 1
}
notinglobalScope()


console.log(config.page)
```